# Console log not outputting object

Tags: reactjs

I'm working through a react.js tutorial and they use:
console.log(props) to help explain things.
I'm using Chrome, and switch to developer tools and console log.
Props is an object that is being passed to a function and it is working in the code.
In the console log all I get is [object Object]
I would like to see the current content of the object.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add a code snippet to understand the mistakes that you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try console.log(props.contact)???

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks!!
Why do you suppose I needed to that when this guy didn't?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44&t=3523s

at 1:24:40

Comment: Glad to be helpful. please check the answer as correct.

Comment: I believe I just did. I'm new around here, just learning my way around.

Answer (score 0):

May you are displaying the props object as a string. So try displaying it as a JSON object.

console.log(JSON.parse(props));`